# Criar uma janela de varredura no MATLAB

Tags: python, matlab

Estou tentando criar no matlab um script que faça uma sub-matriz (janela de busca 3 x 3) percorrer por toda uma matriz maior buscando valores mínimos para cada trecho de 3 x 3 células analisadas. Quando o script encontra esta célula de valor mínimo, ele a coloca como centro da sub-matriz e busca novamente o valor mínimo e assim sucessivamente até uma célula indicada na matriz maior. Já tentei trabalhar com loops, porém como sou iniciante não estou conseguindo.

```
clc
clear
alt= imread('foto_o1.tif')
[l c]= size(alt)
a = 1
b = 7
d= 1
while a < 416
  a= a+1 
  while b < 416 
    b= b+1 
    d= d+1 
    d= alt(1:7, a:b)
  end
end
```

Comment: Hugo, bem vindo ao Stack Overflow! O que você já tentou até aqui? As perguntas devem mostrar um mínimo de esforço de pesquisa. Procure fazer um [tour] e leia o guia [ask]

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas gmsantos, segue uma tentativa inicial para deslocar uma submatriz sobre uma matriz maior, mais especificamente uma matriz de 3 x 3 sobre uma de 244 x 416.clc
clear

alt= imread('foto_o1.tif')
[l c]= size(alt)

a= 1
b= 7
d= 1

while a < 416
    a= a+1
    while b < 416
    b= b+1
    d= d+1
    d= alt(1:7, a:b)
    end
end

Answer (score 1):

Não ficou muito claro, mas vou tentar ajudar, vamos partir para um exemplo simples, vamos criar uma matriz `6x6` para exemplificar:

```
A = [1  2  3  4 5  6;  7 8 9 10 11 12; 13 14 15 16 17 18; 19 20 21 22 23 24; 25 26 27 28 29 30; 31 32 33 34 35 36]
```

OK Isso vai te dar a seguinte matriz:

```
A =

    1    2    3    4    5    6
    7    8    9   10   11   12
   13   14   15   16   17   18
   19   20   21   22   23   24
   25   26   27   28   29   30
   31   32   33   34   35   36
```

Perfeito seguindo sua lógica (se eu entendi bem) você precisa caminhar aplicando uma janela `3x3`, isso quer dizer que você precisaria extrair as seguintes sub-matrizes da matriz principal:

Sua primeira sub-matriz seria:

```
    1    2    3
    7    8    9
   13   14   15
```

Segunda:

```
    4    5    6
   10   11   12
   16   17   18
```

Terceira:

```
   19   20   21
   25   26   27
   31   32   33
```

Quarta:

```
   22   23   24
   28   29   30
   34   35   36
```

A lógica para se fazer isso é realmente caminhar por um loop e ir incrementando a linha e coluna por 3:

```
A = [1  2  3  4 5  6;  7 8 9 10 11 12; 13 14 15 16 17 18; 19 20 21 22 23 24; 25 26 27 28 29 30; 31 32 33 34 35 36]

[l, c] = size(A)

c1=1;
c2=3;

while c1 <= c

    l1 = 1;
    l2 = 3;

    while l1 <= l

       D = A(c1:c2,  l1:l2)
       l1 = l1 +3;
       l2 = l2+3;

    end
    c1 = c1+3;
    c2 = c2 +3;
end
```

O código acima imprime as sub-matrizes mostrados neste exemplo.

Para extrair o valor mínimo dentro de cada sub-matriz você pode utilizar a função `min` do matlab, neste caso adicione após `D = A(c1:c2,  l1:l2)` a seguinte linha `minimo =min(D(:))`

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda ederwander, é exatamente isto que eu preciso. Fiz uma confusão na hora de usar o while e por isso não estava conseguindo.